# Annotation needed from swagger codegen

Tags: swagger-codegen

I need a way to annotate my openapi 3 specification so that swagger-codegen will add an annotation to my java class, such as @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)

Is that possible?

TIA!

Comment: With current API versioning trends toward API evolution, it seems like `ignoreUnknown = true` would be the expected behavior. Eager to see responses to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you could take advantage of mustache templates. Extract mustache files for required language from code-gen jar file and edit the needed class template file. Then, generate client code with `-t pathToTemplates` flag like so:

`java -jar swagger-codegen-cli-2.3.1.jar generate 
      -t C:\SwaggerTemplates 
      -i C:\Swagger.json 
      -l csharp 
      -o C:\Output`

Comment: can you elaborate the answer? From where is this mustasche files ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible.

Here are the steps that worked for me -

1. Download the swagger-code-gen source code either from github or get the zip. I have version 2.3.1 and downloaded from [swagger-code-gen 2.3.1](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/releases/tag/v2.3.1)
2. For Java, update **AbstractJavaCodegen**.java file and add the 2 lines in processOpts() method:

*importMapping.put("JsonIgnoreProperties","com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties");*

// import JsonIgnoreProperties if ApiModel is imported   *importMapping.put("io.swagger.annotations.ApiModel","com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties");*

[image]

3. Save the file and mvn clean install to generate the swagger-code-gen-cli-2.3.1 in target directory
4. Now extract the "pojo.mustache" and any other required file from the above cli jar (located in this path - "swagger-codegen-2.3.1\modules\swagger-codegen-cli\target\swagger-codegen-cli-2.3.1.jar\Java\") to a directory (e.g. spring_template)
5. Add the line "@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)" below @ApiModel in the "pojo.mustache" file 
   [image]
6. Now execute the command with the built cli jar and spring_template in path: 
   java -jar swagger-codegen-cli-2.3.1.jar generate --additional-properties apiPackage=com.xxx.xxx.api,modelPackage=com.xxx.xxx.model,delegatePattern=true,useTags=true,configPackage=com.xxx.xxx.configuration,basePackage=com.xxx.xxx -o app -l spring -i your_swagger_yaml_file.yaml -t spring_template
7. This should build and generate pojo/ model classes with @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) and with import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties in the class.

Answer (score 0):

maven has plugin for swagger

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
  <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>java-codegen</id>
      <phase>generate-sources</phase>
         <goals>
            <goal>generate</goal>
         </goals>

         <configuration>
                          
           <language>jaxrs-spec</language>
           <templateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/swagger-templates</templateDirectory>
           <inputSpec>${basedir}/src/main/resources/v1/swagger.yaml</inputSpec>
           <output>${project.build.directory}/swagger-codegen</output>
           <apiPackage>com.example.api.v1</apiPackage>
           <modelPackage>com.example.api.v1.dto</modelPackage>
           <modelNameSuffix>DTO</modelNameSuffix>
           <configOptions>
             <additional-properties>generateModelBuilders=true,useJackson=true,sortParamsByRequiredFlag=false,useJacksonJsonIgnoreUnknownProperties=true</additional-properties>
             <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
           </configOptions>

         </configuration>
       </execution>
     </executions>
   </plugin>
```

if we are using `swagger-codegen-maven-plugin` to generate code then

```
<additional-properties>generateModelBuilders=true,useJackson=true,sortParamsByRequiredFlag=false,useJacksonJsonIgnoreUnknownProperties=true</additional-properties>
```

will generate DTO with `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)`

Comment: I expected this to be the solution, but doesn't work for me, which version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Using swagger-codegen v2.4.20 or higher, you can achieve it adding the following configuration to your pom.xml

`<additional-properties>ignoreUnknownJacksonAnnotation=true</additional-properties>`

Example

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.20</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <language>java</language>
                <inputSpec>${sourceFile}</inputSpec>
                <output>${outputFolder}</output>
                <modelPackage>${model.package}</modelPackage>
                <generateApis>false</generateApis>
                <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
                <generateApiDocumentation>false</generateApiDocumentation>
                <generateSupportingFiles>false</generateSupportingFiles>
                <generateModelDocumentation>false</generateModelDocumentation>
                <generateModelTests>false</generateModelTests>
                <configOptions>
                    <additional-properties>ignoreUnknownJacksonAnnotation=true</additional-properties>
                    <sourceFolder>.</sourceFolder>
                    <java8>true</java8>
                    <dateLibrary>legacy</dateLibrary>
                    <serializableModel>true</serializableModel>
                    <hideGenerationTimestamp>true</hideGenerationTimestamp>
                </configOptions>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

The other solutions didn't work for me for whatever reason, but this did:

```
<configuration>
    <configOptions>
        <additionalModelTypeAnnotations>@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)</additionalModelTypeAnnotations>
    </configOptions>
</configuration>
```

Credit to this thread: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/3438