# Ignore unknown properties with swagger-codegen-maven-plugin 3.x

Tags: json, parsing, swagger-codegen

I am using swagger-codegen-maven-plugin to generate swagger code from yaml.

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>io.swagger.codegen.v3</groupId>
                <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.36</version>
```

The server keeps on adding new properties, which have not been added to client side yaml.

Client fails with the error

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "keyCode" ....
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:61)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:1127)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:2023)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1700)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownVanilla(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1678)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:319)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:176)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:129)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:313)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:176)
```

I want to add
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
to generated swagger class, so that any new fields on server side, do not break client.

How can the generated swagger code have the @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) ?

I have tried different options including the one at https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/3438.

I also see solutions such as [Annotation needed from swagger codegen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50969588/annotation-needed-from-swagger-codegen). But these solutions are with 2.x jar and I am trying 3.x jar of swagger-codegen-maven-plugin